# How to handle duplicates in sql on union all select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

For an example, if have:

```
SELECT 'A@G.com' AS Email, 2 AS Somenumber, 3 AS Number
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A@G.com' AS Email, 2 AS Somenumber, 5 AS Number
UNION ALL
SELECT 'z@y.com' AS Email, 1 AS Somenumber, 6 AS Number
```

instead of:

[image]

I want  to get:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Just don't include the first row in the `union all`.

Comment: Assuming this is sample data, how do you decide which of the 'duplicates' you want to keep, the one with `number = 3` or `number = 5`?

Comment: it all depends on the Email addresses, I want to just return the rows with no email duplicates

Comment: But you have two rows with the same email, which one do you want to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Email, Somenumber, Number
FROM (
    SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY Number DESC)
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('A@G.com', 2, 3),
            ('A@G.com', 2, 5),
            ('z@y.com', 1, 6)
    ) t(Email, Somenumber, Number)
) t
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

output -

```
Email   Somenumber  Number
------- ----------- -----------
A@G.com 2           5
z@y.com 1           6
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're after one row per email.  You can do that like:

```
; with  all_rows as
        (
        ... your union query here ...
        )
, with  numbered_rows as
        (
        select  row_number() over (partition by email order by somenumber) as rn
        ,       *
        from    all_rows
        )
select  email
,       somenumber
,       number
from    numbered_rows
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

usually when I need to solve problem like this I am going with Devart solution above just my mind working in same way
but here alternate solution which give better execution plan

```
select  Email, max(Somenumber), max(Number) from (
SELECT 'A@G.com' AS Email, 2 AS Somenumber, 3 AS Number
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A@G.com' AS Email, 2 AS Somenumber, 5 AS Number
UNION ALL
SELECT 'z@y.com' AS Email, 1 AS Somenumber, 6 AS Number
) A
group by Email
```

[image]